# Unable to select id when subquery used

Tags: mysql

This is my current query that returns `text` column as result.

```
SELECT text FROM `tableA` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE `id` LIKE '%00%') GROUP BY text
```

But I want `id` also to be selected, but my below query gives error and I'm not sure why.
**(note id selected as well)**

```
SELECT id, text FROM `tableA` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE `id` LIKE '%00%') GROUP BY text


Error:
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY 
clause and contains nonaggregated column 
'search_db.tableA.id' which is not
functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; 
this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

My full query looks like this:

**I'm actually selecting column text from multiple tables and want unique value for text column**

```
SELECT DISTINCT text FROM `tableA` AS `table` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE `id` LIKE '%0.219%') UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT text FROM `tableB` AS `table` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE `id` LIKE '%0.219%') UNION
SELECT DISTINCT text FROM `tableC` AS `table` WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tableC WHERE `id` LIKE '%0.219%')
```

Comment: There are no aggregating functions here, so no aggregating clause required. Problem solved.

Comment: @Strawberry! could you please explain the point. I am also facing the same issue ?

Comment: @Strawberry, I don't get it..which one is not needed? please take a look at my edited post. I posted my full query.

Comment: https://blog.gabriela.io/2016/03/03/group-by-are-you-sure-you-know-it/

Comment: The 'full' query is entirely different from the first query, and incapable of producing this error, so not sure what you want now.

Comment: Each query in the 'full query' is almost the same. So I try getting the result from one table first without duplicate.

Comment: The difference is your first query (ab)uses GROUP BY, while the other queries use DISTINCT. A MySQL option has changed and the default is now in line with most other flavours of SQL. As such any non aggregate column (ie, not a result of an aggregate function such as SUM, COUNT, etc) in the SELECT query _must_ be in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

this means if you want to fetch `id` also, you should add `id` in `group by` statement:

```
SELECT id, text
FROM `tableA`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tableA WHERE `id` LIKE '%00%')
GROUP BY id, text
```

Or you can remove `only_full_group_by` from your sql_mode:

```
set @@GLOBAL.sql_mode = replace(@@GLOBAL.sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '');
```

maybe modify `sql_mode` in current session is more better:

```
set @@session.sql_mode = replace(@@session.sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT id, text FROM `tableA` WHERE `id` LIKE '%00%' GROUP BY text
```

Comment: I've tried this many times, LIKE doesn't go well with group by, thats why came up with subquery idea

Comment: what does not go well with group by as like and group by are being applied to different columns.

Comment: I get error when I try it in phpmyadmin, see my post above for the error

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.